# After adding the maven compiler to version 3.8.1 ,@RequiredArgsConstructor does not initialized

Tags: spring-boot, lombok, mapstruct

According to https://mapstruct.org/documentation/installation/

I added the mapstruct plugins in the poml.xml

```
          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source> <!-- depending on your project -->
                    <target>1.8</target> <!-- depending on your project -->
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <!-- other annotation processors -->
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
           </plugin>
```

After adding the Pluging all my @RequiredArgsConstructor are giving compile error

```
variable recipesService not initialized in the default constructor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide step-by-step: [Using Mapstruct With Project Lombok](https://springframework.guru/using-mapstruct-with-project-lombok/)

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>3.8.0</version>
     <configuration>
         <annotationProcessorPaths>
             <path>
                 <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                 <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                 <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
             </path>
             <path>
                 <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                 <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                 <version>${lombok.version}</version>
             </path>
             <dependency>
                 <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                 <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                 <version>0.2.0</version>
             </dependency>
         </annotationProcessorPaths>
         <compilerArgs>
             <compilerArg>
                 -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
             </compilerArg>
         </compilerArgs>
     </configuration>
 </plugin>
```